# DevExpress MVC Extensions: How to set GridViewSettings.Caption style?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I'm working on a simple ASP.NET MVC 3 (ASPX View Engine) application. I have a GridView control on the page. So I set necessary GridViewSettings with this code:

```
<%
Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings => 
{
    settings.Name = "gvMyGridView";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "MyGridView" };

    settings.Caption = string.Format("My caption");

    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.Width = Unit.Percentage(10.0);
        column.FieldName = "MyField";
        column.Caption = string.Format("MyField Name");
        column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.TextBox;
    });

    ...

}).Bind(Model).Render(); 
%>
```

I have one question: **How can I change style (background and font size) for grid view caption?**

I can set the caption with this code:

```
settings.Caption = string.Format("My caption");
```

And I can change HeaderRow styles with GridViewSettings.Styles.Header, but I can't find a way how to set style properties for caption. Please, help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the caption styles through the [**`ASPxGridView.Styles.TitlePanel`**](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewTitleStyletopic) property:

```
// Example:
settings.Styles.TitlePanel.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: I've tried settings.Styles.TitlePanel, but it didn't help me. Styles don't want to change. I guess maybe some styles from CSS file override it, but I can't find my current title background color in this file for example.